# Why do banks payment validation systems use JavaScript redirects

Tags: javascript, forms, onlinebanking

When you pay through online payment systems ( being with or without 3DSecure), you fill in the form and validate, and from a strictly visual point of view, things seems pretty straightforward. But behind, there is often multiple redirections, which are handled through JavaScript.

Basically, your data is submitted, and you land on a page with a pre-filled form, which is immediately submitted through JavaScript, sometimes multiple times in a row (with fast enough connection, you don't even see those steps from browser).

I was wondering why they do it that way (instead of proper back-end redirections), and I can't find an answer to it.
My guess is that it's just to make it harder for scripts to follow it, but it's still possible to do it (so why bother), and to my opinion, the "dirty aspect" of it (from a coder point of view) is not worth the constraints it gives to scripts that would attempt an automatic validation.

Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: With systems banks use, it's most likely one developer that started it, and now it's easier to just maintain the code that was written a long time ago, instead of refactoring it.

Comment: Even recent systems do it that way though, so there must be some other reason for it to be that way.

Comment: I don't get the down votes and close request on this question. I couldn't find a similar one, and it's not dumb. At least put a comment if something is wrong with that question.

Answer (score 0):

From my view, using the JavaScript will detect the bot or human efficiently.

As you can already saw, how the Google validate the bot.

It's just simple a check box, but it's quite complicated if you try to write the bot to verify or pass the check. (Now I still don't know how to pass by it ^)

Comment: Google captcha is far from being "just a check box" though, there's a whole system attached to it. Plus, the javascript redirects i'm talking about don't even implement those kind of things. They're basically just form validation. Which you can easily emulate with curl for example.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with curl, but they might use javascript to generate more field like: secure_code or do many other thing...
As i said all of above thing, it just create more difficult for you to analytic their system. Inside their system, they must do more about private business or something... to detect and verify you again. With using it, it will eliminate 90% bot  so it's worth to use.

Comment: Yes, I pointed out that possibility in my question, I was just wondering if there was another reason which I couldn't think of.

Comment: Yeah, it's interested question. But my answer might be lack something ;). Hope we have expert about bank security or integration to help.